# React js TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined. I am using react router ^5.2

Tags: reactjs

> I want to pass data from the project page to the details page through
> this code. I have also define details page URL '/project/:id', But facing this error. How can I solve these issues?

```
 constructor({match}) {
    super();
    this.state={
        ProjectPassedID: match.params.id,
    }
}
```

Comment: Your post lacks information regarding the context where this function is called. According to the error you've got, the `match` variable is `undefined` so it's likely related to a problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have solved this issue using withRouter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68595756/i-am-developing-a-news-portal-site-with-react-js-and-laravel-i-want-to-show-eve

Comment: I am facing another problem that I have already posted and the link is above the comment box.  It would be helpfull